# I need help changing the size of my button

Tags: button, size

I've tried the style attribute but it doesn't work and causes `onclick` to not work. Here is the code I used:

```
<button style="width: 100px; height: 75px;" onclick="window.location.href='https://discord.gg/unDRU8a';"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think your code does not have any problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>btn-size</title>
</head>
<body>
   
   <button style="width: 100px; height: 75px;" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.google.com/';">alert</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

the url that you entered has problems. I tried "https://www.google.com/" instead of that and it works well.